# How to correctly convert from Euler angles and multiply quaternions?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, quaternions

We are trying to convert from a local space incremental rotation in Euler (X,Y,Z) = Pitch Yaw Roll to  an absolute world space rotation Quaternion.

We are doing this by converting each incremental rotation to a quaternion and accumulating (through multiplication) Quaternion rotations to give a world space quaternion.

However our result rotations show the object rotating around  world space axes rather than local object axes.

I am following this pseudocode loop and c++, and have built the same in Unity3D (which works correctly since the Quaternion operations are aready provided).

Does anyone have any pointers as to what is going wrong here?

```
Quaternion qacc;
Quaternion q1;

loop
{
    quacc = quacc * q1.degreeToQuaternion(xRot, yRot, zRot);
}

...


void Quaternion::degreeToQuaternion( double yaw, double pitch, double roll) // yaw (Z), pitch (Y), roll (X)
{
    yaw = yaw * M_PI / 180.;
    pitch = pitch * M_PI / 180.;
    roll = roll * M_PI / 180.;

    radianToQuaternion(yaw, pitch, roll);
}


void Quaternion::radianToQuaternion( double yaw, double pitch, double roll) // yaw (Z), pitch (Y), roll (X)
{
    double cy = cos(yaw * 0.5);
    double sy = sin(yaw * 0.5);
    double cp = cos(pitch * 0.5);
    double sp = sin(pitch * 0.5);
    double cr = cos(roll * 0.5);
    double sr = sin(roll * 0.5);

    this->w = cy * cp * cr + sy * sp * sr;
    this->x = cy * cp * sr - sy * sp * cr;
    this->y = sy * cp * sr + cy * sp * cr;
    this->z = sy * cp * cr - cy * sp * sr;
}

Quaternion operator * (Quaternion q0, Quaternion q1)
{
    Quaternion q2;
    double mag;

    q2.w = q0.w * q1.w - q0.x * q1.x - q0.y * q1.y - q0.z * q1.z;
    q2.x = q0.w * q1.x + q0.x * q1.w + q0.y * q1.z - q0.z * q1.y;
    q2.y = q0.w * q1.y - q0.x * q1.z + q0.y * q1.w + q0.z * q1.x;
    q2.z = q0.w * q1.z + q0.x * q1.y - q0.y * q1.x + q0.z * q1.w;

    mag = sqrt (q2.w * q2.w + q2.x * q2.x + q2.y * q2.y + q2.z * q2.z);

    q2.w /= mag;
    q2.x /= mag;
    q2.y /= mag;
    q2.z /= mag;

    return q2;
}
```

Comment: What's going right? When writing tricky mathematical code *make sure you have unit tests*. Don't just expect this will work. A typo where `sr` is actually `cr` could ruin your day.

Comment: People haven't truly grasped yet that world peace can be achieved if we all universally adopt Quaternions and get rid of Euler angles from all software and literature.

Comment: On a more serious note, what is the source of the incremental euler angles? This tells me that you have some numerical integration going on with euler angle and their derivatives as the state vector. Is this correct? The best way to handle this situation is to just go with quaternions aand their derivatives as the state vector. There is a close form equation to convert 3D angular velocity into derivatives of quaternions which you should be able to look up from any standard texts.

Comment: You should use Euler angles for keyframes only and for UI exclusively. In runtime you should work with quaternions calculation intermediate frames using slerp

Comment: After some testing with the Eigen library to replace my code, it seems that Unity and my code using different coordinate systems is the problem, and that swapping x, and y components and inverting z give appropriate Unity Quaternions. I'll test further.

The  close form equation to convert 3D angular velocity into derivatives sounds like it will be useful in the future though!  @cplusplusrat

Comment: @davient I don't know if this is related to what you were saying but you're calling `q1.degreeToQuaternion(xRot, yRot, zRot);` but the signature has `double yaw, double pitch, double roll`. Is that not a mismatch? Shouldn't yaw be `yRot` and pitch be `xRot`? Not sure why Z needs to be inverted, though.

Comment: 1. Try to use good tested quaternion implementation.
2. Remember that "Euler angles"  can represent 12 different rotations, depending on order of multiplication.